# reactjs, sync state with database on db change, or on component mount?

Tags: reactjs

I'm wondering which is the standard practice:

querying the database after every DB update and setting state based on the query? 
or setting the state before the db update (faster UI response), and querying the DB only on component mounting or when it's absolutely necessary?

i also have a slightly separate question, i may as well ask it here. In a case where a component must sync with a db in near-real-time, say a feed like facebook feed, without using redux subscriptions, is setting an interval in react that queries the db automatically, say every 20s, the best way to handle this?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only my opinion so not really and 'answer'

1. Generally when you update a DB it will return the updated object. So what I tend to do is 'optimistically' update state and then update with the returned object (using redux but it should not matter) -- you need to consider errors -- and also network speeds lifi etc... One must also consider that other people may also be updating your db so it is also worth considering this fact which leads onto your next question.....
2. If you need real time updates consider using something like Firebase or if you are using a node server in your stack maybe consider using socket-io? This would then eliminate repetitive and unnecessary calls